# Closing streams using finally

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and just learned I should close streams in a try/catch/finally block but it's forcing me to use another try-catch inside the finally wrap, otherwise I have to throw an Exception.

This code is from an exercise and I'm trying not only to pass it but to establish good coding practices. Could you please have at my closing approach? Feel free to criticise other aspects of the code and tear it apart. That's the only way I'll get better.

```
/* 
Read 2 file names from the console: file1, file2.
Write all the bytes in file1 to file2, but in the reverse order.
Close the streams.

Requirements:
1. The program should read a file name twice from the console.
2. Use FileInputStream to read from a file, and use FileOutputStream to write to a file.
3. In the second file, you need to write all the bytes from the first file in the reverse order.
4. The FileInputStream and FileOutputStream must be closed.

*/

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Solution {

    private void copyArray () {
        FileInputStream input = null;
        FileOutputStream output = null;

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.print("Enter a filename to be read: ");
            String file1 = reader.readLine();
            System.out.print("Enter a filename to write to: ");
            String file2 = reader.readLine();

            input = new FileInputStream(file1);
            output = new FileOutputStream(file2);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[input.available()];

            int count = input.available();
            input.read(buffer);
            for (int i = count-1; i>=0; i--) {
                output.write(buffer[i]);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("General I/O exception: " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                output.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
          new Solution().copyArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: If the code works and you want to improve it rather than solving a problem, the question probably fits better in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You should use the [try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: Exactly. Your learning, or possibly your teaching, is several years out of date.

Comment: NB This is a documented misuse of `available()`. See the Javadoc. And calling it twice is just asking for it to increase between the first and second calls, which will cause your code to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use try with resources

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))){

        System.out.print("Enter a filename to be read: ");
        String file1 = reader.readLine();
        System.out.print("Enter a filename to write to: ");
        String file2 = reader.readLine();

        try(FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file1);FileOutputStream  output = new FileOutputStream(file2)){
            byte[] buffer = new byte[input.available()];

            int count = input.available();
            input.read(buffer);
            for (int i = count-1; i>=0; i--) {
                output.write(buffer[i]);
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("General I/O exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: You should also use a `try-with-resources` for the `BufferedReader`.

Comment: yeah, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Please go through guidelines before posting any question.

Anyways, I believe, this would be correct way to use Java feature - `Try with Resource`

```
private static void copyArray () {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a filename to be read: ");
        String file1 = scanner.next();
        System.out.print("Enter a filename to write to: ");
        String file2 = scanner.next();
        scanner.close();
        try (FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(file1)) ; 
             FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File(file2))){

            byte[] buffer = new byte[input.available()];

            int count = input.available();
            input.read(buffer);
            for (int i = count-1; i>=0; i--) {
                output.write(buffer[i]);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("General I/O exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
 }
```